# Error: Loop takes too long to execute pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Newbie code, how can this script be written better for the error "Loop takes too long to execute" to not appear.

```
//@version=5
condition = ta.cross(deliveryVolumePercentage, 95)
bars_since = ta.barssince(condition)
plot(bars_since)

int secondToLast = 1
while bars_since 
    count = 1
    secondToLast := bars_since[count]
    count := count + 1

plot(secondToLast)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while bars_since` is equivalent to a `while true`, hence it's an infinite loop which won't never end
You need to loop on a condition that **IS NOT forever** true

For example, if you want to loop within the 5 first candles after your cross, the loop will end 5 candles after the cross

```
while bars_since <= 5
    count = 1
    secondToLast := bars_since[count]
    count := count + 1
```